# FBLoginView delegate method is called twice or even 3 times

Tags: ios, crash, facebook-login

This Facebook Login View method `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:` is getting called twice or even 3 times.Why does this happen? and how to prevent this? I'm getting a crash from time to time especially when this method gets called 3 times because of some codes that I need to do inside  `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:`.

Comment: Apparently this bug was filed and fixed in the SDK 3.8 version. However I am still seeing it on 3.11. https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1414348378783720/

Answer (score 2):

I put this line in viewDidDisappear and it worked

```
self.loginView.delegate = Nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem because of this bug on the Facebook SDK. I had fixed it temporarily by putting flags in between the Facebook calls. The flags used to get incremented by 1 each time the function is repeated. I used if condition to check and skip the function being called twice or more, and there by limiting the function call to one.